# How to find all indexes of vector<vector<int>> for the minimum first index

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a 2-D data vector that is unsorted and contains duplicated elements.

How can I find the minimum and all the indexes with the value?

For example, given data `vector<vector<int>> mySol = {{3,1},{1,2},{4,5},{1,3},{1,2}}`, I want to find `{1,2}`, `{1,3}` and `{1,2}` which give the minimum value 1 (based on the first element) and indices 2, 3, and 2.

How to improve the following code snippet? For a big data, the following code seems to be slow, because of `sort`:

```
vector<vector<int>> mySol = {{3,1},{1,2},{4,5},{1,3},{1,2}};
sort(mySol.begin(), mySol.end());

//print out shortest distance
cout << mySol[0][0] << endl;

//print out the number of shortest paths
int nShortest = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < mySol.size(); i++) {
    if (mySol[0][0] == mySol[i][0])
        nShortest += 1;
}
cout << nShortest << "  ";

//print out y-coordinates of the shortest paths in increasing order
for (int i = 0; i < nShortest; i++) {
    cout << mySol[i][1] << " ";
}
```

Comment: Do you want to compare only the first element of the inner vector?

Comment: Also it looks like all your inner vectors are of length 2. If so, perhaps you don't want to use std::vector for them.

Comment: You can first change your first loop to `for (int i = 0; i < mySol.size() && mySol[0][0] == mySol[i][0]; i++) { nShortest += 1;}`. No need to loop through all the vector.

Comment: Yes, the first element is the value for finding minimum, others being coordinates. Also, mySol in vector<vector<int>>  is actually built by the other function in some "mySol.push_back() manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may do the job in linear time:

- first find minimum
- then iterate on minima.

Something like:

```
auto cmp = [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs) { return lhs[0] < rhs[0]; }
auto minIt = std::min_element(mySol.begin(), mySol.end(), cmp);
auto eqToMin = [&](const auto& value) { return (*minIt)[0] == value[0]; }

for (auto it = minIt; it != mySol.end(); it = std::find_if(it + 1, mySol.end(), eqToMin)) {
    std::cout << (*it)[1] << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jarod! Based on Jarod's idea, I modified the code as follows. Use simple min and avoid find_if.  This seems to be faster, avoiding sort and finding minimum.

```
vector<vector<int>> mySol = {{3,1},{1,2},{4,5},{1,3},{1,2}};
auto minIt = std::min(mySol.begin(), mySol.end());
cout << (*minIt)[0] << endl;

int nShortest = 0;
for (auto it = mySol.begin(); it != mySol.end(); ++it) {
    if ((*it)[0] == (*minIt)[0]) ++nShortest;
}
cout << nShortest << " ";

for (auto it = mySol.begin(); it != mySol.end(); ++it) {
    if ((*it)[0] == (*minIt)[0]) {
        cout << (*it)[1] << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: `std::min` doesn't do what you expect [Demo](http://ideone.com/Ze5g3Z). you really need `std::min_element`. For the filtering, it is ok., and `nShortest` is wrong as now input is not sorted.

Comment: You are right, Jarod42. "min" doesn't behave as I expected and thus min_element must be used.